# How do I rewrite this url using php and .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes, seo

I'm building this real estate website and I currently have this template file called 'building.php', which uses MySQL information using POST or GET. The link (with a variable id) for each building looks like this: **realestate.com?building=1**. I have a specific code and title for each building though. Let's say in this case the code is K-001 and the title is 'New offices Brooklyn, NY'. Then I want the URL to rewrite from

'**realestate.com?building=1**' -> '**realestate.com/K-001/new-offices-brooklyn-ny**'

How can I rewrite the url dynamically for each building using a MySQL query?

Comment: are you using any framework? or just plain mvc structure?

Comment: `..com?building=1` is `GET`, not `POST`. Or is it also using `POST`?

Comment: this isn't a mysql question. it's a routing question. mysql has nothing to do with this process - only with how your application handles the info AFTER the rewriting

Comment: @pala_ I do need to use MySQL to do a mysqli_query to find the building title using its ID, no?

Comment: @enigma yes you're right -> I meant GET

Comment: @CédricDhaenens yes, but its nothing to do with this question. The user hits a link that looks like `http://realestate.com/K-001/new-offices-brooklyn-ny`, after rewriting, it would look like `http://realestate.com/controller?path=/K-001/new-offices-brooklyn-ny`. Your php controller would then look at the path, but by that stage, this question has already been answered.

Comment: @pala_ it kinda is a MySQL question if the long form urls are stored in a database, which I think is likely...

Comment: it would be very weird if they were. but even still - .htaccess and apache aren't going to talk to the database to figure out what to do with a url